# an array A[1..N] how many indexes (i,j) are there such that cumulative sum(i,j)%K = 0?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, computer-science

Lets say I have an array A[x1,x2,x3,...xN] of size N.

for N = 4 , A = {x1,x2,x3,x4}. [1 based index]

Now,I have to tell how many tuples (i,j) are there such that i<=j and cumulative sum(i,j) is divisible by K.

For example, N = 4

A = { 3,2,5,7} and K = 5.

Now , For this case the answer is 3. as, ( 1,2 ) [cum_sum = 5 ,divisible by

K(5)], (3,3)

[cum_sum = 5 ,divisible by K(5)] , (1,3) [ cum_sum = 10 ,divisible by K(5)]

are such tuples.

I can do this in O(N^2) easily.But how to do this in O(N) or O(N*log(N)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the problem intends that all the $x_i$ are integers.

This can be done in order $O(N)$ as follows:

Create a (zero-based) vector $C$ of size $K$, initially all zeros.  $C_m$ at stage $m$ of the algorithm represents the number of ways to form a sum of $m \mod K$ using a consecutive sub-sequence of $\{ x_1, \ldots x_m\}$.  Thus after stage $N$, $C_0$ will be one more than the answer to the problem (because we will have counted the empty set, which has a sum vacuously equal to zero mod $K$.

Also create a (zero-based) vector $D$ of size $K$, initially all zeros. $D_m$ at stage $m$ of the algorithm represents the number of ways to form a sum of $m \mod K$ using a consecutive sub-sequence of $\{ x_1, \ldots x_m\}$ that ends at $x_m$.

At stage $0$ change $C_0$ to $1$; this reflects the sum of no elements of the set equaling zero.

At each subsequent stage $n$, for $1 \leq n \leq N$, for $i = 0 \ldots K-1$, do
$$
D'_{(i + x_n)\mod K}= D_i + [i \equiv x_n {}_{\pmod K}] \\
C_i= C_i + D'_i 
$$
where the notation $[i \equiv x_n {}_{\pmod K}]$ means $1$ if $x_n$ is congruent to $i$ modulo $K$,  and $0$ otherwise.

At this point $D'_i$ is the number of ways to form a sum of $i \pmod K$ using a consecutive sub-sequence of $\{ x_1, \ldots x_n\}$ that ends at $x_n$, 
because each of the earlier substrings can lead to sumsthat are offest by $x_n$ from their previous sums, and there is one extra way to choose just $x_n$ which sums to itself. So complete the stage by setting up the the stage $n$ values of $D$:
$$D = D'$$

After stage $N$, the answer is $C_0 -1$.

The time complexity of this algorithm is $O(K)$ for each stages, and there are $N$ stages, so for fixed $K$, the algorithm executes in $O(N)$ time.